# Angular 4 - Http to HttpClient - property 'someproperty' does not exist on type Object

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to change an existing app from using `Http` to using `HttpClient`, however i have an error.

So in my service now you can see the new code vs the old code that's been commented out:

```
constructor(
        // private http: Http
        private http: HttpClient
    ) { }

    getSidebar() {
        // return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/sidebar/edit-sidebar')
        //     .map(res => res.json());
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/sidebar/edit-sidebar');
    }
```

And in my `page.component.ts` I have this

```
this.sidebarService.getSidebar().subscribe(sidebar => {
                        this.sidebar = sidebar.content; // this does not work now
                    });
```

However for the line above which I commented on I get this error now:

```
Property 'content'
 does not exist on type 'Object'.
```

However if I `console.log(sidebar)` I get the following:

```
{_id: "59dde326c7590a27a033fdec", content: "<h1>sidebar here</h1>"}
```

So what's the issue?

Once again, `Http` works but `HttpClient` does not.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can specify the type that is being returned, using an interface, class, etc. For example, you can use something like the following:

```
return this.http.get<Sidebar>('http://localhost:3000/sidebar/edit-sidebar');
```

As an example, Sidebar might be defined as:

```
interface Sidebar {
    _id: string;
    content: string;
}
```

See [Typechecking the response](https://angular.io/guide/http#typechecking-the-response) from the Angular docs for further information:

> ...TypeScript would correctly complain that the Object coming back from HTTP does not have a results property. That's because while HttpClient parsed the JSON response into an Object, it doesn't know what shape that object is.

Comment: if you didn't mentioned `<Type>`, then it take `any` as default return type.

Answer (score 19):

HttpClient parse automatically the JSON response to an Object and the shape of that object is not known, that's why Typescript show this error

alternative solution, using **bracket notation**:

```
this.sidebarService.getSidebar().subscribe(sidebar => {
 this.sidebar = sidebar["content"];
});
```

Answer (score 15):

You can assign the variable(sidebar) an interface to explicitely tell what it will get or assign  to it so it doesnt throw compile time error.

```
this.sidebarService.getSidebar().subscribe((sidebar: any) => {
                        this.sidebar = sidebar.content; 
                    });
```

Answer (score 10):

you can do this like that with type `<any>`

if you do this you will not get that error

```
this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:3000/sidebar/edit-sidebar');
```

Answer (score 3):

**Using bracket notation instead of dot notation to reference** `sidebar['content']` **instead of** `sidebar.content` **will solve the issue.**

The [Type-checking the response](https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response) section of the Angular docs on HttpClient mention's this, although it's not all that clear:

> The subscribe callback above requires bracket notation to extract the
>   data values. You can't write `data.heroesUrl` because TypeScript
>   correctly complains that the data object from the service does not
>   have a heroesUrl property.

Comment: This is very helpful, some APIs do not conform to the type-checking that Angular wants by default with camelCase so this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Error Description**

> ERROR in src/app/home.component.ts(131,20): error TS2339: Property
>   'someProperty' does not exist on type '{}'.

**why Occured ?**

I think this error is in service file , whenever you making http call and that call returns any Object(json) or array of Objects (json) , then yours http call should return Observable or Model of that result type

**Home.service.ts**

```
   connectToServer(data)  {
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/connect' , data)
    }
```

Suppose , I have above Post http call , where i connect to server by passing data inside 'data' and this request returns me connection Object (Json).But where u seen that i didn't specify observable or model for holding result  and if i access the result Object properties from component.ts it will says result.somepropery does not exist on {} .

**Solutions**

First :

```
connectToServer(data) : Observable<any> {
            return this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/connect' , data)
        }
```

Note : Don't forget to import Observable

Second :

```
  connectToServer(data) :  <Connection> {
                return this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/connect' , data)
            }
```

In second case you need to define Interface for declaring Connection Object fields and needs to import here.