# Angular, error TS2339: Property 'tasks' does not exist on type 'Response'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I'm trying to print tasks when I use `res.json()`, I get nothing when I use `res.tasks`. I get another error, only new ones are shown, old ones are not displayed, and if the page is reloaded, then new ones will also be removed.

task.ts

---

```
....

   loadTasks(): Promise<Task[]> {
   const url = `${this.tasksUrl}?access_token=${localStorage.getItem('token')}`;
   return this.http.get(url)
     .toPromise()
     .then(res => res.tasks as Task[]) // res.json()
     .catch(error => this.handleError(error, 'Could not load tasks!'));
}

....
```

---

Error terminal:

```
ERROR in src/app/services/task.ts(30,24): error TS2339: Property 'tasks' does not exist on type 'Response'.
```

---

Error console browser:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined
at FilterByFieldPipe.push../src/app/pipes/filter-by-field.ts.FilterByFieldPipe.transform (filter-by-field.ts:10)
```

and filter-by-field.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterByField',
  pure: false
})

export class FilterByFieldPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items, key, value) {
    if (items.constructor === Array) {
      return items.filter((item) => item[key] === value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the old http or the new httpClient?

Comment: I'm using a new httpClient,

Comment: Try using this `.then((res:any) => res.tasks as Task[])` for the terminal error. For the other one, you need to show how you call your pipe. You're probably calling it on an undefined variable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47202177/angular-4-http-to-httpclient-property-someproperty-does-not-exist-on-type/47202304

Comment: And thank you, the advice with an error in the console helped.

Comment: I noticed that if I create two different accounts, create tasks from them, then tasks are not assigned to one user, how can this be fixed?