# Property 'request' does not exist on type 'HttpClientModule'

Tags: angular

Understand [HttpClient is being replaced by HttpClientModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47202177/angular-4-http-to-httpclient-property-someproperty-does-not-exist-on-type/47202304), so I'm going from **HttpClient --> HttpClientModule** as:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 
{ 
  HttpClientModule,
  //HttpClient, <-- original
  HttpRequest,
  HttpEventType,
  HttpResponse,
} from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable()
export class MyService 
{
  constructor(private http: HttpClientModule) { }   // (private http: HttpClient)  <-- original

  public mymethod( 
    this.http.request(req).subscribe(...);
}
```

problem is on the last line,

> this.http.request(req).subscribe(...);

yeah, `http.` has nothing come up.

Answer (score 1):

You must change to get or post request and change in constructor to

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient)
```

And

```
this.http.post(req).subscribe(...);
```

or

```
this.http.get(req).subscribe(...);
```

Your source code should be:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import 
{ 

  HttpClient,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpEventType,
  HttpResponse,
} from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable()
export class MyService 
{
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }  

  public mymethod( 
    this.http.post(req).subscribe(...);
}
```

Comment: HttpClient is being replaced not introduced.

Comment: maybe the problem of my end.

Answer (score 1):

Import and inject HttpClient:

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,...

this.http.request will be available, e.g.:

[Sample service](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kdmftg?file=app/northwind.service.ts)

Also make sure you are using an Angular version that supports the described approach.

Comment: HttpClient is being replaced not introduced.

Comment: Http was replaced with HttpClient in Angular 4.3 (or so), the correct imports are HttpClientModule in the app.module.ts, and HttpClient in the data service.

Comment: HttpClientModule was imported in app.module.ts, HttpClient was imported in MyService now giving me trouble, installed angular version is 7.x

Comment: maybe the problem of my end.