# How to use model to set data type of an Observable in Angular

Tags: angular

I've a very basic question related to a service. I've this method `getAllArticlesFromDb` in my service that will fetch data from an API using `HTTP`'s GET call. Here is the method:

**article.service.ts**

```
getAllArticlesFromDb() : Observable<any> {
  return this._httpClient.get('https://obscure-tundra-38074.herokuapp.com/api/articles');
}
```

I thought I should not use `<any>` as I know the structure of the Object that is returned by the API. So I created a model:

**article-model.ts**

```
export class Article {
    articleid: string | undefined;
    title: string | undefined;
    content: string | undefined;
    date: string | undefined;
    contributor: string | undefined;
}
```

The problem starts here. Why I can't modify my service method like this:

```
import { Article } from './model/article-model';

getAllArticlesFromDb() : Observable<Article> {
  // same GET call
}
```

I'm getting this error:

"Type 'Observable Object' is not assignable to type 'Observable Article'.
The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Article': articleid, title, content, date, and 1 more."

Please correct my mistake.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 4 - Http to HttpClient - property 'someproperty' does not exist on type Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47202177/angular-4-http-to-httpclient-property-someproperty-does-not-exist-on-type)

Comment: @R.Richards, Sure I'll have a look. There is an answer below also. I'll check that first. I'll show both the answers to my tech lead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the generic overload on the [`HttpClient` `get`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get) call. Then the return will match what is specified in your method signature.

```
import { Article } from './model/article-model';

getAllArticlesFromDb() : Observable<Article> {
  return this._httpClient.get<Article>('https://obscure-tundra-38074.herokuapp.com/api/articles');
}
```

---

After reading the end point url and the name of your method you likely meant to return an array of that type in which case change it to `Array<Article>>`.

```
import { Article } from './model/article-model';

getAllArticlesFromDb() : Observable<Array<Article>> {
  return this._httpClient.get<Array<Article>>('https://obscure-tundra-38074.herokuapp.com/api/articles');
}
```

Comment: I think this answers my question. will accept this in 7 mins

Comment: Did you check the response of my API as well?

Comment: @Tanzeel looks like an array of objects to me so the second code block in my answer using `Array<Article>` is the way to go.

Comment: Yup, thats an array of objects. the data is fetched from a mongodb collection actually.

Answer (score 1):

Because `this.http.get` returns an `Observable<any>`. You can specify what object type get returns with `this.http.get<Article>` or cast it with `this.http.get(<parameters>) as Observable<Article>`